# Error writing xpath for Dynamic web Table inside a iframe

Tags: html, xpath, rpa, automationanywhere

I am using object cloning of Automation Anywhere to identify a value inside a Dynamic web table.
For selecting this value, my validation is to check if

1. Column with **Upload Date** is greater  than or equal to certain value.
2. Column with **Document type Name** has certain text .

If the above two conditions are met I have to select the corresponding **Id#** from the column and click on it.

I want to write a xpath for the same with the validation checks as variables.

But I have problem identifying the column names with td tags.

I am able to write until this Xpath:

`//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr[td]`

which is identifying all the td values but if I place the

`//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr[td/a[@id,'idvalue']]`

where id value = `"contentplaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrInkuploadedTime"` or any id value for that matter is not working.

For the **td 's with span** I have replaced them with *span* and also tried with **Column names and contain tags**.

Still not working. I am attaching the html code for the same. If anybody can help me identify what I am doing wrong. Please do.

I want to write something like `//table/tr/td[upload Date > or ="my variable" ]` and `td[Doc Type Name = "my Variable"]/td[doc Id]`.

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="whiteBg" border="0">
                                    
    <tbody><tr class="tableSubHead" style="padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;">
        <td>
            <a id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblId" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl00$hdrlblId','')">&nbsp;ID #</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlbltypeName" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl00$hdrlbltypeName','')">Document Type Name</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblInRefPkg" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl00$hdrlblInRefPkg','')">In Referral Pkg?</a>
        </td>
        
            <td>
                <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblapprovalstatus" class="content">Approval Status</span>
            </td>
        
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblpdfsize" class="content">PDF Size (in Bytes)</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblNoOfPages" class="content">Number Of Pages</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlnkUploadedTime" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl00$hdrlnkUploadedTime','')">Upload Date Time</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblUploadedby" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl00$hdrlblUploadedby','')">Uploaded By</a>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_hdrlblAction2" class="content">Action</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sdod" align="left" style="padding: 4px;">
        <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a onclick="window.open('DMCViewDocsDownload.aspx?QryAdapterKeys=Eq8ctIKSF7iDsUkLJB8IwOamBj7OjW4h56RKsZ10/0kCNxTNFhcpUiZJ6psrfQd0d5pwoCs2YDkMFWq0Zb119Gtf1fEBBKxDDvKMOSVWBMr/WXzQkdWUA3f+38ZXnLCGPW8BTpgp96gAmy6golmawHaKxFRcqIel90VwfZQ1K3lCOtqDlospiZMt54qF31dN8Kys3m6UyPcBQUWpL57/iw==RZy62fPm5bAaRcEWPBUoIt5qxjfbAFFSxzHT6oY5bL8=', 'ViewDocs','height=450,width=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');return false;" id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblId_0" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl01$lblId','')">12345678</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName_0" class="content">Test Data finder</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblInRefPkg_0" class="content">Y</span>
        </td>
        
            <td>
                <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblapprovalstatus_0" class="content">N/A</span>
            </td>
        
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblfilesize_0" class="content">00000</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblnoofpages_0" class="content">12</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime_0" class="content">11/23/2015 09:38 AM</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadby_0" class="content">John</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 60px">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd" style="padding: 4px;" align="left">
        <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a onclick="window.open('DMCViewDocsDownload.aspx?QryAdapterKeys=snizu1LROpZWar7u9Y+DYUDu6GDgZJX4M8SBF6MrGbxEgrh4WoiKBFRFX2i/sKJ06UHdHUq11MSKsOp9dBHNjdlCK/l1poGCZxgXEzf8ejcHVGHy3t5Rvi6i7FdWXUKuXMcS8nwh+GlPheaxS62k54O8DVay8bn+1IE8OHnGVt6t2mUqkjB/H/NpNU8OKY/bwxjz4mERH9udeUnOZEuX5w==k8GkZ8QbApXofjvbTsmSaM2r6l10ba8orWK0r4IJm2Y=', 'ViewDocs','height=450,width=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');return false;" id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblId_1" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl02$lblId','')">888888</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName_1" class="content">Test Data2</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblInRefPkg_1" class="content">N</span>
        </td>
        
            <td>
                <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblapprovalstatus_1" class="content">N/A</span>
            </td>
        
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblfilesize_1" class="content">222333</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblnoofpages_1" class="content">52</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime_1" class="content">11/23/2015 06:08 AM</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadby_1" class="content">Test Automation</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 60px">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sdod" align="left" style="padding: 4px;">
        <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a onclick="window.open('DMCViewDocsDownload.aspx?QryAdapterKeys=XxsvvVtOjq1YUIOtwubnsZen5QvczUFxgfu/qzqnX5hLQXTDLrXH+0L1aPm8kTe/thIfvqa00sQqzh3EV8Of1HGWSVyzVHh4VV/RHBN3CAX3kVe7UUrRhpK4bcZpdKlKIbVe3AAvDnClHLLSle3sTsXtJyCJrOv2w4cFxeMPiHxAZcKsFHCBREG0Zl0ySa+nKSG8qf1EKDFQYdkkbqIp2g==4AfEni+qTI+I0xHagckSDPN5m+sFKN9gSG2PPafAry4=', 'ViewDocs','height=450,width=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');return false;" id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblId_2" class="anchorBlueBold8" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolderMain$rptviewdocs$ctl03$lblId','')">444444</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName_2" class="content">Test Review</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblInRefPkg_2" class="content">Y</span>
        </td>
        
            <td>
                <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblapprovalstatus_2" class="content">N/A</span>
            </td>
        
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblfilesize_2" class="content">1234567</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lblnoofpages_2" class="content">7</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime_2" class="content">11/18/2015 05:52 PM</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadby_2" class="content">Jane</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 60px">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: none" align="right">
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little convoluted, but if I understand correctly what you need, let's assume that your benchmark upload date is `10111999` and your document type name is `Test Review`, then this xpath expression

```
//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[number(substring-before(translate(.[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime")],'/',''), ' ')) > 10111999]/../../td/span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")][text()='Test Review']/../preceding-sibling::td/a
```

will select

> 444444

which is the iID# for that document.

Comment: Thank you i. I would have never thought to write it that way. I am thinking this place holder '/','' is converting  it to normal digits . so 11/18/2015 to 11182015.  But since we are comparing the dates and the first two digits are month.  Let's say our date in the table is 10182015 and the value we have given is 11182014.  10/18/2015 is after 11/08/2014. But when we convert them to digits we are not gonna get the same value.  I may have misinterpreted myself before but is there any way we can compare the dates with out this issue.

Comment: My objective is to find the date in web table that is the same or after the variable date.  So if my given input date is 07/25/2019. I want to check for the dates that are available there on the webtable if it is either on the same day or after 07/25/2019.

Comment: So if web table 07/26/2019 I want to find it but if the web table has 08/26/2018 then I want to ignore it.  Is there some way we can do this .  I can give my input variable as month date and year separately.  Can we write such that first we compare years and then dates.

Comment: .For finding upload date with just Doc Id name this xpath seems to be not working . What is wrong with this xpath?       `//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")][text()='TestData2']/../../td/span/[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime")]`

Comment: @Rpadevs - as to your last comment, the correct xpath is `//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")]/../preceding-sibling::td/a`. I'll get back to you on your date questions in the other comments.

Comment: Fleming.  Thank you.  But I was actually trying to get all the upload dates if given `text()='TestData2'`.  So I can compare each date with my input variable in my code itself rather than in xpath.  I have tried  `//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")][text()='Title Search - TSG']/../../td/a[@id = "contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime"]`  and

Comment: `//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")][text()='Title Search - TSG']/../td/span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime")]/a`  but no success.

Comment: @Rpadevs - " I was actually trying to get all the upload dates if given text()='TestData2'": there's only one upload date in the row containing `TestData2`.

Comment: Fleming - I wrote this . I am thinking this will get us all the upload dates with `Testdata` as Doc Text.   Now I am trying to find if I can insert a date range for upload date.. If there is a better way to write it. Please advise.  `//table[starts-with(@class,"whiteBg")]/tbody/tr//span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbltypeName")][text()='TestData2']/../following-sibling::td/span[contains(@id,"contentPlaceHolderMain_rptviewdocs_lbluploadeddatetime")]'. `This should get us all the upload dates with matching text ` Test data2 `if any present, right?